# Why SSL_CONNECT blocking on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, openssl, arm64

When I ported this code from windows to linux I faced a problem. This code works perfectly on Windows, but on Linux ARM64 is blocked at the moment when SSL_CONNECT is executed. The code that follows SSL_CONNECT is not executed.

build flags:-lcrypto -lssl -lgumbo -I/$PREFIX/include/openssl

[$PREFIX/include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtcyH.png)

[$PREFIX/include/openssl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY39Q.png)

SSL_connect after "trying to connect\n" [strace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvxAS.jpg)

headers:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#ifndef _WIN32
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#else
#include "winsock2.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "ws2tcpip.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#endif
```

code:

```
Response sendHTTPS(Request& request) {
#ifdef _WIN32
        WSADATA wsaData;
        WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData)) {
            return Response();
        }
#endif 
        std::string req = request.to_string();
        addrinfo* pAddrInfo;
        getaddrinfo(request.uri.host.c_str(), "443", 0, &pAddrInfo);

        SOCKET connection = socket(
            pAddrInfo->ai_family,
            pAddrInfo->ai_socktype,
            pAddrInfo->ai_protocol
        );
        if (!connection)
            return Response();

        int error = connect(connection, pAddrInfo->ai_addr, pAddrInfo->ai_addrlen);
        if (error)
            return Response();

        SSL_library_init();
        SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
        SSL_load_error_strings();

        SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_method());

        SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        if (!ssl)
            return Response();

        SSL_set_connect_state(ssl);
        SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, request.uri.host.c_str());

        int sock = SSL_get_fd(ssl);
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, connection);

        error = SSL_connect(ssl);
        if (error <= 0) {
            /*int err;
            std::string what;
            while ((err = ERR_get_error())) {
                char *str = ERR_error_string(err, 0);
                if (!str)
                    break;
                what.append(str);
                what.append("\n");
            }
            throw std::exception(what.c_str());*/
        }

        int len = SSL_write(ssl, req.c_str(), req.size());
        if (len <= 0)
            return Response();

        std::string result = "";
        char buffer[16384] = { 0 };//16 kib
        int bytes_recv = 0;

        do {
            bytes_recv = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if (bytes_recv > 0)
                result.append(buffer, bytes_recv);
        } while (bytes_recv > 0);

        closesocket(connection);
        SSL_shutdown(ssl);
        SSL_free(ssl);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

        return Response(result);
    }
```

Comment: SSL_connect would block until TLS/SSL handshake is finished with other side. Are you sure the other side is responding properly?
You may want to check with wireshark what is happening.

Comment: Also SSL_write is not guarantied to send all request, you should check if its returned value (len) is equal to req.size()

Comment: I checked it on windows and that works. I,m sure other side works correctly.

Comment: Is rDNS needed?